# MVC Removing Custom validation rule via Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

Here is my scenario. I have a form where the user can submit a work ticket. I'm using Model data. In my model I have 3 properties that have data annotations as shown below

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a start date.")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateWorkStarted { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a end date.")]
    [GenericCompare(CompareToPropertyName="DateWorkStarted", OperatorName=Enums.GenericCompareOperator.GreaterThan, ErrorMessage="End Date must be occur after the start date.")]
    [Display(Name = "Closed Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateClosed { get; set; }
```

One of the annotations is a cusatom validator that will check that the start date (DateWorkStarted) does not occur after the end date (DateClosed).

Here is the custom validator

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.addMethod("genericcompare", function (value, element, params) {
    // debugger;
    var propelename = params.split(",")[0];
    var operName = params.split(",")[1];
    if (params == undefined || params == null || params.length == 0 || value == undefined || value == null || value.length == 0 || propelename == undefined || propelename == null || propelename.length == 0 || operName == undefined || operName == null || operName.length == 0)
        return true;
    var valueOther = $(propelename).val();
    var val1 = (isNaN(value) ? Date.parse(value) : eval(value));
    var val2 = (isNaN(valueOther) ? Date.parse(valueOther) : eval(valueOther));

    if (operName == "GreaterThan")
        return val1 > val2;
    if (operName == "LessThan")
        return val1 < val2;
    if (operName == "GreaterThanOrEqual")
        return val1 >= val2;
    if (operName == "LessThanOrEqual")
        return val1 <= val2;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("genericcompare", ["comparetopropertyname", "operatorname"], function (options) {
    options.rules["genericcompare"] = "#" + options.params.comparetopropertyname + "," + options.params.operatorname;
    options.messages["genericcompare"] = options.message;
});
});
```

Now the form consists of 2 buttons a regular submit button which submits the form and only creates the ticket and keeps it open. But there is another button that opens up a dialog to allow the user to enter close ticket information (In this case entering the start and end date). and there is a button on the dialog that will submit the form using not only the fields that were filled out in the main form but the fields from the dialog too). This is all working fine.

What I'm trying to do is in the case when the user is just creating a ticket the form will still try and evaluate my custom validator and since I am not putting any data in the dates at this point the validation will fail. How can I disable the custom validator when the Create Ticket (submit) button is clicked.

Here is what I thought would do the tick but it has no effect. (I put this in the click event of the CreateButton

```
        $("#CreateButton").click(function () {
            $("#CloseDescription").rules('remove');
            $("#DateWorkStarted").rules('remove');
            $("#DateClosed").rules('remove');
            $('#DateClosed').rules('remove', 'customcompare');

        });
```

I know having the customcompare specific remove string in there for DateClosed looks redundant since the rules('remove') should handle all the rules for a particular selector but that was my latest attempt to see if it worked (call it grabbing at straws).

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own required if attribute.

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
    private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
        {
            if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName);
        rule.ValidationParameters["desiredvalue"] = DesiredValue is bool ? DesiredValue.ToString().ToLower() : DesiredValue;

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
[RequiredIf("Condition", "Value", ErrorMessage="Error Message")]
    public string Property{ get; set; }
```

**EDIT**
You should add below script in order to be able to use the client side validations. (Preferable in a separate JS file)

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', ['dependentproperty', 'desiredvalue'], function (options) {

    options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;
    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {

    var desiredvalue = parameters.desiredvalue;
    desiredvalue = (desiredvalue == null ? '' : desiredvalue).toString();
    var fieldId = parameters.dependentproperty.split('_')[0];
    var controlType = $("input[id$='" + fieldId + "']").attr("type");
    var actualvalue = {}
    if (controlType == "checkbox" || controlType == "radio") {
        var control = $("input[id$='" + fieldId + "']:checked");
        actualvalue = control.val();
    } else {
        actualvalue = $("#" + fieldId).val();
    }

    if (desiredvalue.indexOf(',') == -1) {
        if ($.trim(desiredvalue).toLowerCase() != $.trim(actualvalue).toLocaleLowerCase()) {
            var isValid = $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
            return isValid;
        }
    }
    else {

        if ($.trim(desiredvalue.split(',')[0].toLowerCase() != $.trim(actualvalue).toLocaleLowerCase() || $.trim(desiredvalue.split(',')[1].toLowerCase() != $.trim(actualvalue).toLocaleLowerCase())))
        {
            var isValid = $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
            return isValid;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I'm able to remove The Required rules of the property OK. The only thing i'm not able to remove is the custom validator (customcompare). The custom compare evaluatesd the Start and end date fields (which are in a dialog that only appears when the "Create And Close Button is clicked' This validates that the start date is not a date greater than the end date. In the case where the user is not closing the ticket (Create submit button) the validation should not occur., so I need a way to tell javascript to remove the customcompare rule in this case.

Comment: Can you add new boolean property with required if (condition) attribute? based on that enable / disable the validation. This should work client and server side. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for... but my first thought was you could take advantage from the required if.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. It ended up being the actual CustomCompareAttribute class that I was using. I needed to check if the value passed into the validator (ClosedDate) is not null in addition to the the actual compare logic.